Apply predicate to all_tab_cols.data_default in Oracle
The Oracle system view, all_tab_cols has a column, data_default. This column is declared as LONG, but when the view is queried, the value comes back as a string if the default value for a column is is an expression. For example:
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  col1 NUMBER DEFAULT mysequence.nextval
);

The query SELECT data_default FROM all_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'TAB1' AND column_name = 'COL1'; returns the string '"MYUSER"."MYSEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL"'.
If I change the predicate to WHERE table_name = 'TAB1' AND data_default LIKE '"MYUSER"%', the query fails with ORA-00932 "Inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG"
How can I get the default value in o form where I can apply a predicate to it?
Besides the attempt above, I've also tried casting the column to a character type. I get the same error. Parsing the output of DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL is far too expensive and error-prone to be used.

You can use PL/SQL to convert the LONG into a varchar2 simply by assignment, and then call it from SQL or wrap a view around it and query the view:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dba_tab_columns_data_default(in_owner IN varchar2, in_table_name IN varchar2, in_column_Name IN varchar2)
  RETURN varchar2
AS
  var_data_default varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
  
  FOR rec_expr IN (SELECT *
                     FROM dba_tab_columns
                    WHERE owner = in_owner
                      AND table_name = in_table_name
                      AND column_name = in_column_name)
  LOOP
    var_data_default := rec_expr.data_default;
  END LOOP;
  
  RETURN var_data_default;
END;  
/

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_tab_columns_ext
AS
SELECT owner,
        table_name,
        column_name,
        data_type,
        data_type_mod,
        data_type_owner,
        data_length,
        data_precision,
        data_scale,
        nullable,
        column_id,
        default_length,
        f_dba_tab_columns_data_default(owner,table_name,column_name) AS data_default,
        num_distinct,
        low_value,
        high_value,
        density,
        num_nulls,
        num_buckets,
        last_analyzed,
        sample_size,
        character_set_name,
        char_col_decl_length,
        global_stats,
        user_stats,
        avg_col_len,
        char_length,
        char_used,
        v80_fmt_image,
        data_upgraded,
        histogram,
        default_on_null,
        identity_column,
        evaluation_edition,
        unusable_before,
        unusable_beginning,
        collation
  FROM all_tab_columns
 ORDER BY owner,table_name,column_id

Now query:
SELECT data_default FROM all_tab_columns_ext WHERE table_name = 'TAB1' AND data_default LIKE '"MYUSER"%'

This works as long as your default fits in 4KB, but I've never seen a default not do so. The same can be used on dba_tab_cols, dba_ind_expressions, dba_tab_partitions, and anywhere else a LONG is unnecessarily used for what will never exceed 4KB. The function above uses the dba_* views but of course you can adapt it for all_* if you don't have the select any dictionary priv.

Thanks. I may not be able to use this as the DB belongs to a customer and I don't think I can make changes to it. In any case, this has given me some ideas about how I can handle this in application code.

@ArtKaufmann If you can't create objects, you can make a small change to this solution and use it as a single query. Instead of creating a function, you can define the function in a WITH clause and then use that function in the query. The final query would look like: WITH function f_dba_tab_columns_data_default ... END; SELECT owner, ....

A new column was added in Oracle 23c, data_default_vc, which is described in the documentation as:



Column
Data type
NULL
Description




DATA_DEFAULT_VC
VARCHAR2(4000)

Default value for the columnThis column may truncate the default value.



So from that version you can do:
SELECT data_default FROM all_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'TAB1' AND data_default_vc LIKE '"MYUSER"%';

fiddle
(Presumably not relevant for the OP, but included for future visitors...)

Glad to hear they finally listened. Hard to imagine they held on to forcing long on us for so many years...

Thanks. Unfortunately my application has to work with 12c, 18c, 19c, and 21c!
